# How to check if the value of a specific key is the same in all objects within a grouped object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, data-structures, higher-order-functions

I have a group of objects in which I would like to check whether a specific key always has the same value in every single object in this group.

**Here's is my simplified example:**

*The console.log of the group..*

```
console.log(this.groupedObjects);
```

*..returns the following..*

```
{One: {…}, Two: {…}, Three: {…}}
```

*..that looks like this when you expand it:*

```
One: {type: "One", high: 5, medium: 0, low: 10, selected: false, …}
Two: {type: "Two", high: 56, medium: 0, low: 0, selected: false, …}
Three: {type: "Three", high: 79, medium: 0, low: 0, selected: false …}
```

I want to check whether the key `selected` has the value `false` in all objects. If so, then I would like to trigger another method.

```
Object.entries(this.groupedObjects).map(([key, item]) => {
  if (/** Every objects key "selected" has the value "false" */) {
    // trigger next method
  }
});
```

How can I solve this or what is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array **every** method. JS **every** method checks if all elements in an array pass a test. The below code will return true if every selected is false and based on that result you can execute another function.

```js
const data = {
  One: { type: 'One', high: 5, medium: 0, low: 10, selected: false },
  Two: { type: 'Two', high: 56, medium: 0, low: 0, selected: false },
  Three: { type: 'Three', high: 79, medium: 0, low: 0, selected: false },
};

const ret = Object.keys(data).every((x) => !data[x].selected);
console.log(ret);
```

**For example:**

```
if(ret) {
  //execute next function
}
```

Comment: It's working! Many Thanks. I haven't known Object.every yet. :)